# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Node JS Server

Tags: mysql, node.js

Following a tutorial online to incorporate mysql into node js, and I am receiving an error on code line 12.  Wondering what went wrong. (server.js file)

```
10| <div class="=">

11|     <div class="col s12">
```

> > 12|         <% if (items.length > 0) { %>}

```
13|             <table class="table">

14|                 <thead>

15|                     <tr>
```

> 0) { %>}
>               
>                   
>                       
>                           ID
>                           Name
>                           Description
>                           Location
>                           Actions
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                       
>                           
>                               
>                               
>                               
>                               
>                               
>                                   " class="btn btn-success">Edit
>                                   " class="btn btn-danger">Delete
>
> **There are no records available**

Comment: Looks like the "items" object doesn't exist. Change line 12 to be: <% if (items && items.length > 0) { %>} 
-Why- it doesn't exist is difficult to explain without more code (it could potentially be a whole range of things)

Answer (score 2):

This means there was no value of variable `items` passed to template render so it was `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Because of `items` variable is undefined. whenever you try to find a length of an undefined variable you will see this type of error. Please, console.log/print the `items` there should be an issue with that only.